# Why did the experimenter touch the circular plate in this demonstration?

Tags: electrostatics, charge, coulombs-law

In [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B5LVoU_a08c&t=0m10s) introductory physics experiment demonstration, the experimenter went through the following procedure:

First, he charged the rectangular plate by rubbing it with fur.

Next, he laid a circular plate over the rectangular one and then touched it with his index.

Finally, he charged the sphere to demonstrate Coulomb's law.

What was the purpose of his touching the circular plate with his index?

Comment: Do you mean he touched it with his index *finger*?

Comment: Yes, the index finger, or, simply, the index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The surface that the experimenter rubbed was an insulator.  The insulator acquired a charge when it was rubbed.  When the experimenter put the metal circular plate on the charged insulator, it induced a polarity on the surface of the plate because like charges repel.  Assuming that the insulator has a negative charge on it, this means that electrons in the metal plate moved to the top of the plate.  When the experimenter touched the plate, he effectively grounded it, allowing electrons to leave the plate and move onto him.  Once the experimenter removed the metal plate from the insulator, it had a net charge on it (in this case, a positive charge).

Note that a similar argument can be given if the insulator is positively charged, but in that case, electrons will transfer from the experimenter onto the metal plate.

Comment: Thank you. A small follow up question: In the second case (insulator positively charged), since his electrons went onto the plate, thereby creating a positive charge "on" him, would the electrons flow upward from earth to the experimenter ?

Comment: @Hilbert, yes they would.  The experimenter is standing on the earth, which has practically an infinite number of electrons to donate (or absorb) due to its huge mass.